# Python3 UnitTests not running in different directory

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, directory

My file structure is similar to this.

```
Project\
-->src\
----->__init__.py
----->user_input.py
-->tests\
----->__init__.py
----->test_user_input.py
```

I am attempting to run tests on user_input.py from test_user_input.py. The test_user_input.py runs, however no tests are ran and the program finishes. However, when the test_user_input.py file is in the src directory it has no problem completing all of the tests successfully.

I have blank "**init**.py" files in each directory as I have read to do online. I thought from there I can just import the file as normal, but this is clearly not the case.

Here is the the test_code.py file which runs the tests

```
import unittest
import user_input


class TestUserInput(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_miles(self):
        self.user_data = user_input.UserInput()
        self.user_data.miles_driven = 400
        self.assertEqual(self.user_data.get_miles_driven(), 400)
```

I have researched this quite a bit and cannot find what I am missing. Why does the file run but no tests are completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, super simple fix that I just found. For some reason unittests will run without

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

when in the same directory as the code that it is testing, however you need this if it is in a different directory. Maybe others can comment on the reasoning behind this. Ended up getting it fixed!